# String Reversal Program, Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I've recently decided to start learning Kotlin, and I've started a mini project to create a program that outputs a user inputted string, but in reverse.

I've built a version that uses Typed Array to store a user given string, then reverses each word within that array before returning the string but in reverse. Currently it doesn't work as intended, when the program is run, it doesn't crash and I have no error logs, but the program output looks like: **[Ljava.lang.string;@2d112c3**. The output I'd be expecting would be, for example: user given string: **Hello World**, program output: **olleH dlroW**. I've had a look around online and seen a few other programs of a similar nature but I so far, have been unable to fix the issues in my version.

acitivty_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/useButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="158dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="159dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="275dp"
        android:text="Reverse String"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/userInput"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="240dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="101dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter a Word or String"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/programOutput"
        android:layout_width="210dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="101dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:text=""
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/useButton"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/userInput" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.kt

```
@file:Suppress("UNUSED_CHANGED_VALUE")

package com.example.stringreversal

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.TextView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val userString = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.userInput)
        val submitButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.useButton)
        val changeText = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.programOutput)

        submitButton.setOnClickListener {
            val getString = userString.text

            val typedArray: Array<String> = getString.split(" ").toTypedArray()
            val count = typedArray.count()
            var nul: Int = 0

            while (nul <= count) {
                for (word in typedArray) {
                    word.reversed()
            }

            nul++ }

            val reverseString = typedArray.toString()

            changeText.text = reverseString
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i've removed your manifest file to make your question easier to read, because it's really just a basic and standard manifest and doesn't make much of a difference here :) you, or anyone who feels it is relevant, can add it back if they disagree

Comment: Okay yeah that's cool, wasn't entirely sure whether it would be useful or not so best to add it initially just in case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should use `typedArray.joinToString(" ")` instead of `typedArray.toString()`

Comment: I think this will put an extra space between each element. You could use `typedArray.joinToString("")` (`""` instead of `" "`) if you don't want that.

Comment: So this does fix the output problem, thanks very much for the help. Would you know how to reverse each element of the array aswell? With this, it outputs the string correctly, but the string is not reversed at all. I thought what I'd put in the loop would work but it doesn't seem to be.

Comment: You could reverse string like this `val reversedString = string.split(" ").map({it->it.reversed()}).joinToString(" ")`

Answer (score -1):

change

```
val getString = userString.text
```

to

```
val getString = userString.text.toString()
```

`userString.text` returns an object of `Editable` type. To get string value from EditText you have call `toString()` from Editable object.

Comment: The output happens because of the call to `toString` on the array.